# Create "fixed" object (hard or movable)

Tags: mesh

I would like to put the mesh's into a "fixed" body, so that it behaves like a real object (moving or static). Currently the meshes are mixing which is actually not natural. I have drawn an example of this: The bubbles at the bottom flow into each other as usual. In the upper picture the bubbles move to the side, because the inner bubble also needs space. Can someone tell me how to do this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello,what kind of object is this? is it supposed to be animated? please give more details

Comment: in the end I want the bubbles to squeeze against each other and not flow into each other, see example picture